How do I fix the indent on the wrapped text-part in description subitems?
For some odd reason, the text being wrapped when using a \subitem inside a \begin{description} starts before the subitem itself.
Code
\begin{description}
  \item [Lorem:] ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \subitem \texttt{test}: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit (se \cref{fig:vue-directive} i \cref{app:appendiksA}).
...
\end{description}

Visual representation (PDF)

How can I fix it so that it either:

Starts on the same place as the subitem title
Starts after the colon (:) of the subitem title (preferred)


EDIT
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}       % For including images
\usepackage{hyperref}       % For hyperlinks
\usepackage{geometry}       % For setting margins
\usepackage{tocbibind}      % To include bibliography in TOC
\usepackage{setspace}       % For line spacing
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}   % For Norwegian language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % For Norwegian characters
\usepackage{csquotes}       % For quotes
\usepackage{parskip}        % For no indentation
\usepackage{todonotes}      % For todo notes
\usepackage{epigraph}       % For epigraphs
\usepackage{xcolor}         % For colors
\usepackage{times}          % For Times New Roman font
\usepackage{float}          % For floating figures
\usepackage{comment}        % For comments
\usepackage{listings}       % For code listings
\usepackage{adjustbox}      % For adjusting table width
\usepackage{soul}           % For highlighting text
\usepackage{hyperref}       % For hyperlinks
\usepackage{cleveref}       % For clever references
    
% Set APA style for biblatex
\usepackage[
    style=apa,              % apa style
    backend=biber,          % use biber backend
    language=norsk,         % use Norwegian language
    sortcites,              % sort citations
    url=true                % include url in citation
    ]{biblatex}             % use biblatex

% Set up cleveref
\crefname{chapter}{Kapittel}{Kapittler}
\crefname{section}{Seksjon}{Seksjoner}
\crefname{subsection}{Underseksjon}{Underseksjoner}
\crefname{appendix}{Appendiks}{Appendikser}
\crefname{figure}{Figur}{Figurer}
\crefname{table}{Tabell}{Tabeller}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{norsk}{
    nodate = {u\adddot å\adddot},
    andothers = {et al\adddot}
 }
 
% Set page margins
\geometry{
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
}

\sethlcolor{yellow}

% Set line spacing
%\onehalfspacing
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

% Title page
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}

        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{resources/Logo_Primary.png}\\[1cm]

        {\Huge\textbf{[REDACTED]}

        \vspace{0.5cm}
        {\LARGE [REDACTED]}

        \vspace{1.5cm}

        \textbf{[REDACTED]}

        \textbf{[REDACTED]}

        \vfill

        \large
        [REDACTED]
        \today

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

% Foreword
\include{chapters/00/00-foreword}

% Table of contents
\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Chapter 1: Introduction
\include{chapters/01/01-introduction}

% Chapter 2: Methodology
\include{chapters/02/02-rev03}

% Chapter 3: About
\include{chapters/03/03-about-[REDACTED]}

% Chapter 4: Experience
\include{chapters/04/04-rev02}

% Chapter 5: Tools
\include{chapters/05/05-technology}

% Chapter 6: Analysis & Discussion
\include{chapters/06/06-analysis}

% Chapter 7: Conclusion
\include{chapters/07/07-conclusion}

% Chapter 8: Reflection
\include{chapters/08/08-reflection}

% Chapter 9: Appendix
\include{chapters/09/09-appendix}

\printbibliography

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please can you show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Where is defined \subitem? In standard lists it doesn't exist ...

@Mensch Hi! Yes, of course - please check my edit. Do you need anything else? I don't have much to go on besides walls of text...

@Zarko I'm not entirely sure what you mean... I am kinda new to LaTeX and \subitem seems to work fine here? The document gets compiled without errors. I added an edit to show the setup.

As far I know LaTeX, subitem is not defined to be used in any kind of lists (but I may be wrong). Please, make your document example much shorter and compilable as it is. Most of the your code is unknown to us.

@Zarko You're probably right. As I said, I'm kinda new to LaTeX, so I don't know. The document compiles just fine; no errors, nor warnings. That being said, I'm curious to know what you mean by "most of your code is unknown to us" - am I using something that doesn't exist?

We haven't your files. Make short example and explain what is your problem. It is not clear.

To long for the comment  ...
Sorry, it is not entirely clear what is your problem. As far as I know LaTeX, \subitem is not defined in any list package. If you like to insert subordinate list to some item in list, than you need to nest lists like as shown in the next MWE (Minimal Working Example):
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   first item
\item   second item with sub items:
        \begin{itemize}
    \item   sub item 1
    \item   sub item 2
        \end{itemize}
\item   third item
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}

which gives:

In the case, that with subitem you means that some item has more paragraphs, Than code for such case is something like this:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   first item
\item   first paragraph in the second item:
   
   second paragraph in this item \lipsum[1][1-2]
   
   third paragraph in this item  \lipsum[1][3-4]
\item   third item
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}


